# Doctrine clear() and many to one relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I need to import large data from csv file (about 1m records).
For avoid memory leaks I tried bulk insert from doctrine documentation:

```
$batchSize = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {

    //code

    $em->persist($user);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
}
$em->flush(); //Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
$em->clear();
```

The problem is my insert contains "many to one" relations and everytime I use clear() object duplicate entries from this relation.

Is there any possibility to detach entity and avoid duplicates?

Comment: As a side note: It is always recommended to not use Doctrine when doing large bulk operations. You should use PDO for such tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is. You need to perform smart clean. Meaning that you provide entity type that you want to clear. Example :

```
$em->clear(SomeEntity::class);
$em->clear(OtherEntity::class);
```

this will remove from EM only those types and leave everything else. In that way you can reuse those other objects.

Comment: This is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/7928

Answer (score 0):

Using an ORM for importing large data is pretty time and memory consuming. I never find a way of make a fast and sane import with Doctrine. Besides the import I made this way are a PITA to maintain.

After many years of importing data, the most effective way I found is :

- CSV import in temporary table (LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL or COPY in pgsql)
- Make an insert or update query (INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY in MySQL)
- Do the more specific thing in either SQL or PHP depending on the complexity

This way I can import dozen of big CSV files in seconds.

Hope it help.